# Can't view uploaded image CakePHP4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I was making some simple blog site for practice and I was trying to show uploaded files inside the webroot/img/xxx/abc.(jpg,jpeg,png) .  In the controller, I can upload files and add in DB but can't show it to the view file I don't know why.

This is where I want to show my uploaded files (view.php)

```
 <td><?= $this->Html->image($post->titleImg_file_name, ["height"=> 50, "width"=>50]) ?></td>
```

and this is the Controller where I upload files.

```
public function add()
{
    $post = $this->Posts->newEmptyEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->getData());
        $file = $this->request->getData("titleImg_file_name");
        // If no dir exits, make one
        $dir = realpath(WWW_ROOT . "img" . DS . date("Ymdhms"));
        if(!$dir){
            $dir = mkdir(WWW_ROOT . "img" . DS . date("Ymdhms"), 0744);
            $realPath = WWW_ROOT . "img" . DS . date("Ymdhms");
            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $realPath.DS.$file["name"]);

            $post->titleImg_file_name = date("Ymdhms"). "/" .date("Ymdhms").$file["name"];

            // dd($post);
            
        }

        if ($this->Posts->save($post)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The post has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'));            
    }
    $users = $this->Posts->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $tags = $this->Posts->Tags->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);

    $this->set(compact('post', 'users',"tags"));
}
```

and this is the viewController.

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $post = $this->Posts->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
    ]);

    $this->set(compact('post'));
}
```

Any help I would appreciate.

Comment: I hope you apply proper validation for the file data in the patching stage, otherwise you'd have a possible unrestricted file upload vulnerability that allows for path traversal and arbitrary file types!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. I created the wrong path.